# How do I store an integer correctly in the SharedPrefences in Flutter without getting a null?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I want to save an Int which I can reuse in a new class. For this I used `SharedPreferences`. The problem is when I want to open the Int on my new page then I get only a null out.
But I noticed that when I do a hot restart and then switch to the page no null comes out but what I saved before. Where is my error?

**Here I save the value**:

```
  Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {

    int msgId;
//I fetch json from a page and store the value at msgId. I just don't have it in my code sample in here 
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    msgId = (prefs.getInt('msgId'));
    msgId = (prefs.getInt('msgId') ?? jsonData[0]["msgId"]);
          prefs.setInt('msgId', msgId);

  }
```

**Here I retrieve the saved value (on a new page):**

```
  String url ='MyUrl';
  int msgId;
  // int intMsgId;
  _loadCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      msgId = (prefs.getInt('msgId'));
      prefs.setInt('msgId', msgId);
      print(msgId);
    });
  }

  Future<String> makeRequest(String text) async {
    _loadCounter();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      msgId = (prefs.getInt('msgId'));
      prefs.setInt('msgId', msgId);
      print(msgId);
    });

    print("------MSG_ID------");
    print(msgId);
    print("------MSG_ID------");
    //print(msgId.length);
    if (msgId != null) {
      var response = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(url),
          headers: {
            "x-requested-with": "xmlhttprequest",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "content-type": "application/json",
          },
          body: jsonEncode({
            "messages": {
              "msgId": msgId,
              "refId": msgId
            }
          }));
      print(response.body);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably because you don't `await` the `SharedPreferences.setInt` method.

your code:

```
prefs.setInt('msgId', msgId);
```

change to:

```
await prefs.setInt('msgId', msgId);
```

because `SharedPreferences.setInt` is async.

Comment: I put an await in front of it but I still get null out of it

Comment: You probably haven't finish getting the `msgId` yet when calling `fetchAlbum`. Make sure you have a value from `jsonData[0]["msgId"]`. 
**`The problem is when I want to open the Int on my new page then I get only a null out.`**, try to pass the int value via your page constructor to simplify your code.

Comment: Okay thanks and how exactly do you do that?

Comment: Using something like this: `class YourPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int msgId;

  YourPage(this.msgId);

  @override
  _YourPageState createState() => _YourPageState();
}

class _YourPageState extends State<YourPage> {
  int get _msgId => widget.msgId;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   // build widget with your msgId
    return Scaffold(
      ...
    );
  }

}` . Then create the Page with `YourPage(msgId);`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would do this:

```
// other UI code
child: FutureBuilder(
        future: prefs.getInt('msgId'), // your future
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
           
            return Center(child: Container(child: Text('data: ${snapshot.data}')));
          } else {
            // We can show the loading view until the data comes back.
    
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can already understand your answer but what my real problem that I now do not know how to write it explicitly in my example?